# Viewpager (With Custom Toolbar)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I used UIL for viewing image using viewpager.
I have a fullscreen activity with a custom toolbar(linear layout).
When I Clicked the screen the linearlayout toolbar will be invisible.
But when I scroll on the next page, The linear layout is visible again.
[image]
Like the picture above,
for example, I clicked the page#2, the toolbar will be visible,
but when I switch page, the toolbar is still there.
(I'm creating an image viewer like in facebook).

package com.thesis.juandirection.picasso;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.FailReason;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.assist.ImageScaleType;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.FadeInBitmapDisplayer;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.listener.SimpleImageLoadingListener;


import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * @author Sergey Tarasevich (nostra13[at]gmail[dot]com)
 */
public class ImagePagerFragment extends BaseFragment {

    public static final int INDEX = 2;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_image_pager, container, false);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);

        pager.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        pager.setCurrentItem(getArguments().getInt(Constants.Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, 0));


        return rootView;
    }

    private static class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        ArrayList<String> IMAGE_URLS = new ArrayList<>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private DisplayImageOptions options;
         LinearLayout linearLayout;
        ImageAdapter(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .considerExifParams(true)
                    .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                    .build();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

             container.removeView((View) object);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Constants.IMAGES.size();
            //return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
            Log.e("Constants", "" + Constants.closed);
            IMAGE_URLS = (ArrayList<String>) Constants.IMAGES.clone();
            View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
            linearLayout= (LinearLayout) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.layoutHide);
            imageLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (linearLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });

            assert imageLayout != null;
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(IMAGE_URLS.get(position), imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                    String message = null;
                    switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
            view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
            return imageLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view.equals(object);
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }



    }
}
```

XML file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="1dip">



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutHide"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where is your code for adding toolbar in xml ?

Comment: My toolbar is the Linearlayout.. with ID of layoutHide. I made linear layout look liked toolbar.

Comment: Well i don't find anything with toolbar name.if you want to use toolbar you should use Light.Theme.NoActionBar in your styles.xml and in your layout where you want to show the toolbar ,there you have to write something like  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mytoolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@color/pccolor"
        android:elevation="4dp"
       >
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

Comment: and then bind this toolbar in your activity.if you still not certain then reply back.

Comment: sorry, I know i don't include toolbar widget. what im doing is making a linear layout that just look like toolbar.

Comment: i don't think that will work when your using the concept of viewpager.try it and if you find the solution ,do post back.

Comment: Well, Im about to give up on trying. 
will that work if i use toolbar? and if i clicked the ViewPager the toolbar will hide?

Comment: yes by using this there is way that you can setVisibility to GONE.But why do you have to hide the toolbar.how many tabs you wanted?

Comment: I know you are familiar with facebook app. when viewing a photo, when you click the photo, the toolbar will apear, (the tag options,etc..) and when you click the photo again, it will hide. I'm willing to explain what i want if you don't get my point. I just wantet my project to be more presentable.

Comment: Well if this is your question then you don't need a toolbar.Toolbars are replacement to ActionBar.you cant directly create a layout (Relative layout)and inflate it at bottom and make it visible and invisible upon click events

Comment: From your answer, i think i have an idea. thanks so much..